# Внесение данных из файла (txt) в односвязный список c++

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

С++
В файле записаны фамилии в таком виде:
"Через ентер"

Иванов 
Сидоров
.....

Как мне внести эти данные в односвязный список? Сам новичок потому буду благодарен за подробный разбор

Comment: Разбор чего? Вы ничего не предоставили. В чем у вас проблема? Если что-то не понятно, то обращайтесь к своему преподавателю.

Comment: 1. какая реализация списка? Своя, может - STL или чего?

Comment: Получаете текст и формируете массив односвязный - это что?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте этот код в качестве примера, но не используйте его как финальную версию кода, который Вам нужен.

Список:

```
class List
{

    struct Node 
    {
        std::string data;
        Node *next;
    };

public:

    List()
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    void addValue( std::string const& val )
    {
        Node *n = new Node();
        n->data = val;
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    int popValue()
    {
        Node *n = head;
        std::string ret = n->data;

        head = head->next;
        delete n;
        return ret;
    }

private:
    Node *head;
};
```

Пример:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>

std::ifstream infile;
List pplList;

try
{
    infile.open("....", std::ifstream::in );

    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline( infile, line ) )
    {
        pplList.addValue( line );
    }
}
catch( std::exception const& ex )
{
    if( infile.is_open() )
        infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Что здесь творится?  "объявлен 22 часа назад требующим правки участниками Vlad from Moscow, Harry, kff, Vladimir Gamalian, alexolut, так как вопрос слишком общий

В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, какие подходы используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.
Если вопрос можно переформулировать согласно правилам, изложенным в справке, отредактируйте его."

Comment: @qwertyytrewq, здесь все по-справедливости: чтобы не читать таких сообщений, нужно, как минимум, показать имеющийся код и указать на те места, которые стали причиной появления ошибок (или же, просто не понятно как работает данный код). Тогда будет понятно, в чем _конкретно_ нужно помочь человеку. А так - это называется _напишите за меня все, я схожу сдам_

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
#include <string>

int main() {
    /*объявляем односвязный список*/
    std::forward_list<std::string> fl;

    /*открываем файл*/
    std::ifstream fin(R"(text.txt)");

    /*заполняем*/
    std::string str;
    if(fin.is_open()) {
        while(fin >> str)
            fl.push_front(str);
        fin.close();
    }

    /*печатаем содержимое списка*/
    for(auto it = fl.begin(); it != fl.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример мне нравится больше, чем мой. Плюсую. Только raw-strings тут зачем?

Comment: Вот мой вариант
while (!file1.eof())
  {
   for (t = phead; t != NULL; t = (*t).next)
   {
    file1 >> (*t).element;
    (*t).next = new (node);
    t = (*t).next;
   }   
  }
Мне кажется, что ошибка в условии, но я не могу её исправить
P.S. ваш вариант вроде логичен, но компилятору не нравится, хз почему